# Send UTF-8 character to WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, encoding, utf-8, wcf-configuration

How can i configure WCF service / client to send UTF-8 characters to the service?
I want send norwegian, finnish, romanian text like this "ţşîăâăâşţŞŢĂÎÂ" 
My binding is like this:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBindingConfiguration" receiveTimeout="00:21:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"   messageEncoding="Text"

                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what makes you think this doesn't work? E.g. do you get an error, or is the data mangled in some way?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, the service and client to get the messages in UTF8, but when i show them in my service/client console the special characters don't appear like they were sent.
If i send "îăşţ" it appears in console "îast", that's what it tricked, only in Debug i saw that the service/client receive them correct but in console i see different.

Comment: UTF-8 text encoding by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no configuration necessary. [basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx) already uses UTF-8 text encoding by default.